# SQL scripting and queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, scripting

I am a net admin; though I take interest in coding (python at the moment), I do not consider myself experienced with SQL scripting and queries. I understand basic syntax, and have run a few queries here and there when absolutely necessary for my day-to-day duties- I have never written my own SQL scripts.

I have been tasked with creating a SQL script that queries a database table on a number of seperate servers (specifically, number of print devices contained within a table) and outputs the values to a text file.

The scenario is that there are 25 separate print servers that reside on separate networks in different geographical locations. I assume they all belong to the same root domain, but may be members of different sub-domains. The print server is running a software which manages printers and stores them as values in a database table. The goal is to query each of these servers for number of devices contained in the SQL table, and output the data to a text file. We want to know how many devices there are in the table; how we accomplish this does not matter... so I could either print the names of each device in the table to the file, print the number of entries stored on the device table... does not matter- so long as we can tell how many devices are contained in the table.

Ideally, this script would be able to be run from 1 central location, and query all 25 servers (assuming routing is set up to facilitate this). If that is not practical, the script can be run separately on each network.

So far I know I need the following information:

1) IP/host name of the server hosting the DB.

2) Admin credentials to log into the box (windows creds).

3) Administrative creds to access the DB itself (SQL creds).

4) Name of the DB/table where the target information is stored.

I could then potentially utilize the bcp.exe utility to query for and extract a list of devices contained in a table to a text file.

Any advice for the newbie? Is my thought process correct? How would you go about creating a solution for this problem? If somebody could please verify that I have the right idea in creating this script, or explain how they would logically go about completing this task, I would appreciate it. If you want to start me off with a basic framework to start from, that would be even better :) but I don't expect that in the least. Thanks for any help/suggestions you may have!

Answer (score 0):

You will need the right permissions on each of the machines and you can use BCP to read from the table in each machine. BCP is a SQL Server program external to SQL Server (its built to run from command files/command line),easy to use and very fast.

Comment: Great, thank you for the input. I do have a couple questions pertaining to your suggestion. I should explain that I have been tasked with creating a SQL script that can be run from one central machine to query all of the other print servers which hold the data we need in a SQL DB.

When you say we need the right credentials, do you mean that we need to run the script as a user with admin credentials to the DB/server, or can specific credentials be coded into the script to use for each server? I'm wondering, because the servers do not share the same admin account.

Comment: Please don't run the script with Admin credentials - its unnecessary and rather unsafe. You need to create a user in SQL Server that has the rights to execute the sql (the user needs select permission on the table(s) being queried). Then in bcp you provide the user name and password or just the user name if using windows security for this user.